# How to do successive commits into github repository?

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails, github

I already did my first commit into github. But now I have checked out the already committed repository using 'git clone `<repo name>`'. Now after updating my code I want to commit back the new code into my git repository. How to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have cloned your GitHub repo using an ssh address like `git@github.com:user/repo.git`, all you need to do is to:

```
 git push REMOTENAME LOCALBRANCHNAME:REMOTEBRANCHNAME
```

like:

```
 git push origin
```

would push the current branch to the repo named 'origin' (the default name when you make your clone)

See [GitHub pushing](http://help.github.com/remotes/#pushing) help page for more.